# What is the status of patent 8459282

Tags: uspto

I am trying to determine if the patent [US8459282](https://patents.google.com/patent/US8459282B2/en?oq=US8459282) is still active or if it has been abandoned.

Answer (score 1):

The most reliable way to determine if a US patent's status is the [US Public Pair](https://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair). In this case go to the US Public Pair site, get past the CAPTCHA, select "Patent Number" and enter "8459282" (without quotes). The current status is "Patented Case" which means the **patent is active**. You can check on the status of the patents fees which are up to date. The patent claims priority from an earlier application dated 12-21-2008 and the patent should expire 20 years from this date as there are no patent term adjustments.

An easier but not as official way to check on the status of a patent is just looking it up on patents.google.com. If you do this for [US8459282](https://patents.google.com/patent/US8459282B2/en?oq=US8459282) you'll get much the same information.